# How to get a single JSON object in JSON Model?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I defined a default model in manifest.json:

```
"dataSources": {            
        "mainService": {
            "uri": "/.../vehicleCollection",
            "type": "JSON"
        }
    },
```

Then get a sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel by:

```
 var model = oView.getModel();    
 var oObject = model.getJSON("/VEHICLES(0001)");
```

What I want is a VEHICLES which vehicleId is 0001, instead, it returned the whole VEHICLES array in string:

`oObject = "{"VEHICLES":[{"vehicleId":"0001","route"：...} {"vehicleId":"0005","route"：...} ..."`

I was wondering is there any convenient way to get a single data object ? I am trying to bind this data to my detail page in master-detail template.

Ref: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html

====Update====

JSON structure
(result of `model.oData` and data get from `"/.../vehicleCollection",`):

`{"VEHICLES":[
    {
        "vehicleId":"0001",
        "route":"..",
        ...
    },
    {   "vehicleId":"0005",
        "route: "..",
        ...
     }]
 }`

====update=====

I'd like to share my workaround(is it OK to put them here?), I admit it's very ugly, so I hope to make it more elegant by using UI5 API.

Master.controller.js

`_showDetail : function (oItem) {
                var bReplace = !Device.system.phone;
                this.getRouter().navTo("object", {
                    objectId : oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("vehicleId")
                }, bReplace);
            },`

Detail.controller.js

```
_onBindingChange : function () {
var oView = this.getView(),
    oElementBinding = oView.getElementBinding(),
    oViewModel = this.getModel("detailView"),
    sPath = oElementBinding.getPath(),
    oResourceBundle = this.getResourceBundle(),
    ObjectId = sPath.match(/'(.*?)'/)[1],

var JSONObject = oView.getModel().getJSON();

JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSONObject);

function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}

var oneVehicle = getObjects(JSONObject, "vehicleId", ObjectId);

oViewModel.setProperty("/route", oneVehicle[0]['route']);
},
```

Detail.view.xml

```
<ObjectStatus text="{detailView>/route}"/>
```

Comment: Can you try : 
`var oData = model.getProperty("/VEHICLES(0001)").getObject();
console.log(oData);`

Comment: @Rahul Bhardwaj  `model.getProperty("/VEHICLES(0001)")` returned undefined

Comment: Can you please paste your vehicleCollection and `console.log(model.getData())` ?

Comment: getData return `Object {VEHICLES: Array[11]}  ` and VEHICLES[3].vehicleId = 0001. Is it becase that JSON model don't know the key(vehicleId)...    _I did model.oData before, same effect as `getData()`._

Comment: I don't know why I get a down vote, is there anything I should fix?

Comment: Can someone explain why this question is getting downvotes? It seems well presented and thought out. Furthermore the issue is a live and real one that impacts real life apps.

Comment: Please check the revisions of this questions. There are quite some reasons for downvoting. The title is misleading. The question lacked required details which were added after answers came in. It looks like the autor did not RTFM...

Comment: @Tina: It's getting complicated. The context of your question changed completly. Please open a new questions for the Master-Detail related question.

Comment: @matbtt Re my query on the down votes - thanks for the pointer, and I see  why now. +1 for patience.

Comment: @Tina - going back to your first revision - could it be that you are misunderstanding how to route from a master view to a detail view. This is clearly explained in the tutorial at https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/f96d2522a5ca4382a274ae3c6d002ca0.html and pay special attention to the pattern: employees/{employeeId} in the manifest which illustrates the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed solution works but it does not embrace best practices and I strongly recommend not to start to code like that. You should always use `getProperty` to access model data. In your example you access vehicleId like that:

```
var vehicleId = model.getProperty("/VEHICLES/3/vehicleId");
```

If you need the whole vehicle use:

```
var vehicle = model.getProperty("/VEHICLES/3");
```

Comment: Your answer does not get the vehicle object based on the vehicleId but based on position in the list. Is that correct ?  Maybe some kind of xpath query would work /vehicles/[vehicleId.=0001] maybe?

Comment: yes, @VanquishedWombat That's exactly what I wanted! because the app is a master-detail page, I found that template in detail page didn't work, I know the vehicleId  of the object that is clicked in master page, but not sure I can get position.

Comment: @Tina To check - are you doing this to access the selected vehicle details in the detail-view controller? If so no need to 'look up' the vehicle based on id - instead get the binding context from the view which is a handle on the vehicle and you can access all of the attributes via getProperty(). I was interested in a similar req because of some lazy-loading I had to do for deferred detail-related data. My case was for project > tasks > time logs, with the project as master and task as detail then when a task was selected I had to load DB time logs data into a tab so I needed the task key.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat: The JSONModel only supports index based access on lists.

Comment: @matbtt Understood. However the OP says 'What I want is a VEHICLES which vehicleId is 0001...' then 'I am trying to bind this data to my detail page in master-detail template'... so I am asking for clarification of what she actually needs to do as she may be making life more difficult than needed and the OP's question may be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

`model.getData()` will get you the object. And once you get the object you can use the key i.e. `model.getData().VEHICLES` which will give you the value that is array now to access the third element `model.getData().VEHICLES[3]` .

**So your answer would be :**

```
model.getData().VEHICLES[3].vehicleId ;
```

**Note:** This is some assumption of your json but if can do a **console.log(model.getData()) or place JSON.stringify(model.getData())** paste your json structure to the question and let us know which particular element you want to access it would be easy.

Comment: If somebody has downvoted an answer please care to explain why.

Comment: @matbtt ok an upvote for you but I dont think my solution deserve a downvote though :) . And also if you could add how it is more efficient to your answer it would be great.

Comment: As mentioned your solution works, that's not the point. But it does not encourage to do the things right. You could drive a nail into a wall using a hammer, but it would also work with any hard object... but the hammer would be the smartest solution.

Comment: Your answer might not be an best practices, but it gives a way to look deeper into the model, thanks.